# react use effect not stopping on exit condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, setinterval

I'm trying to make a typewriter effect from scratch with the help of the `setInterval` function but when the word is done being typed the component remounts again with every interval.

```
export default function Typewriter() {
  const name: string = 'Mouhib Ouni';
  const [word, setWord] = useState<string>('');

  useEffect(() => {
    if (word.length < 11) {
      console.log(word.length);
      setInterval(() => {
        setWord(word + name[word.length]);
      }, 1000);
    }
  }, [word]);

  return <div>{word}</div>;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you wanted to use a timeout, not an interval. I doubt you wanted to create as many intervals as the word length

Comment: You need to clear the interval in the `useEffect` cleanup - https://blog.logrocket.com/understanding-react-useeffect-cleanup-function/

Comment: Like the above said, either useTimeout or return a function from `useEffect` (the "cleanup function") that will clear the interval. What exactly is the visual effect you're trying to go for here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `setInterval` will create waves of looping, which is not what you want. Using a `setTimeout` will kick off a 1 second delay followed by your `setWord` function. With `setInterval`, using the cleanup function in your `useEffect` is mandatory. With `setTimeout`, I'd say it's good housekeeping, but not totally needed. Here is the modified `useEffect`:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  let timeout;
  
  if (word.length < 11) {
    console.log(word.length);
    timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      setWord(word + name[word.length]);
    }, 1000);
  }

  return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
}, [word]);
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/z4fbcm)